# Error Too many open files in Universal Image Loader Sockets

Tags: android, sockets, universal-image-loader

Use the library [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) when scroll often happens the following error

```
A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc: 77] Check failed: table_mem_map_.get() = nullptr ashmem_create_region failed for 'indirect ref table': Too many open files
```

checking socket connections via adb

```
adb shell ls -l /proc/[pid]/fd
```

returns many socket connections

```
.....
    lrwx------ u0_a118  u0_a118           2016-08-05 11:11 81 -> socket:[283581]
    lrwx------ u0_a118  u0_a118           2016-08-05 11:11 82 -> socket:[283585]
    lrwx------ u0_a118  u0_a118           2016-08-05 11:11 83 -> socket:[284572]
    lrwx------ u0_a118  u0_a118           2016-08-05 11:11 84 -> socket:[284576]
    lrwx------ u0_a118  u0_a118           2016-08-05 11:11 85 -> socket:[284580]
    lrwx------ u0_a118  u0_a118           2016-08-05 11:11 86 -> socket:[284584]
    lrwx------ u0_a118  u0_a118           2016-08-05 11:11 87 -> socket:[284588]
    lrwx------ u0_a118  u0_a118           2016-08-05 11:11 88 -> socket:[284592]
    lrwx------ u0_a118  u0_a118           2016-08-05 11:11 89 -> socket:[284596]
    lrwx------ u0_a118  u0_a118           2016-08-05 11:11 9 -> socket:[284246]
    lrwx------ u0_a118  u0_a118           2016-08-05 11:11 90 -> socket:[284600]
    lrwx------ u0_a118  u0_a118           2016-08-05 11:11 91 -> socket:[284604]
    lrwx------ u0_a118  u0_a118           2016-08-05 11:11 92 -> socket:[284611]
    lrwx------ u0_a118  u0_a118           2016-08-05 11:11 93 -> socket:[284612]
    lrwx------ u0_a118  u0_a118           2016-08-05 11:11 94 -> socket:[283606]
.....
```

Anyone have any suggestions?